# javascript jquery response HTML into a div do not retrieve all HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a Ajax call with jquery and putting the content inside a div like this:

```
$('#replace').html(response);
```

But it is not replacing all the content I got from 'response'.

When I do :

```
alert(response)
```

I see all the HTML code with no problem.

But when I do:

```
$('#replace').html(response);
```

It does not put all the HTML code from response.

When I do an alert

```
alert(response);
```

I got this (which is correct):

#

```
    <div id='replace'>      
            <tr onclick='javascripot:gravaJOBparaView(5746);' ondblclick='fnOpen(5746);' >
                      <td class='preview' title='8746' >8746</td>
                      <td>XXXX</td>
                      <td>xxxxx</td>
                      <td>xxxx</td>
                      <td>xxx</td>
                  <td>xxxxx</td>
                  <td title='xpto'>XXXXXX</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td> <br/>18:00</td>
                  <td>22/07/2012</td>
                  <td title='Check XXXXX' class='popups' ><a href='#popup_5746'><img src='xpto.png'  alt='Check XXXXXX' width='40px'></a></td>

        </tr>   
  </td>
```

#

But When I do the:

```
$('#replace').html(response);
```

It puts this code in the div 'replace':

#

```
   <div id="replace">       

                  8746
                  XXX
                  XXXX
                  XXXX
                  XXXXX
                  XXXXX
                  RXXXXXX

                   <br>18:00
                  22/07/2012
                  <a href="#popup_5746"><img width="40px" alt="Check XXXXX" src="xxxxxx.png.png"></a>
  </div>
```

#

As you can see for some reason it does not put all the tags from response.

What should I do?

Comment: I Also try
    replaceWith()

But do not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML isn't valid. `<tr>` must be in a table tag.
Replace

```
<div id='replace'>
```

by

```
<table id='replace'>
```

Replace the last `</td>` by a `</table>`

http://jsfiddle.net/wk4eD/1/

Two element must not have the same id in your page

Comment: Thanks!
You are right!

For some reason the .html(id) do not work right when I try to add content inside a table like I did.  But when I did what you say it works! also its also work like this:
    `<div id'replace'>`
       `<table>`
         `<tr><td>XPTO</td></tr>`
       `</table>`
    `</div>`

Answer (score 1):

You need to mind the html nesting rules.  `<td>` must be inside a `<tr>` which must be within a `<table>` (technically you need a tbody or thead, but browsers are tolerant of this one).

You should use this service:
http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Under More Options, choose to validate HTML fragment and match your doctype.  You can use that to make sure the HTML is valid before trying to stuff it into that div.

Answer (score 0):

you have to close the div you might want to use

```
 </tr> 
  </div>  
  </td>
```

at the end. JQuery might replace text before 
 because it cannot find proper div end statement.